ImportError: Could not import sentence_transformers python package. Please install it with `pip install sentence_transformers.`
I have this line of code where I'm using model(all-MiniLM-L6-v2) from SentenceTransfomerEmbeddings from hugging face. I'm getting this error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils'. ImportError:Could not import sentence_transformers python package.Please install it with `pip install sentence_transformers` " due to this import statement "from langchain_community.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings". 


tried upgrading, downgrading langchain,python.
tried pip install sentence-transformers. got no error. pip list showed sentence_transformers. but still showed same error when I ran my code.
tried upgrading torch


Langchain version? Please show the sentence-transformers line of pip list.
